# Question about $L^{1}$ and $L^\infty$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I need help showing that $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1$ but it isn't dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. I really don't have a clue how to do this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean to be dense? Ask yourself this question, and hopefully you will know what to do next.

Comment: Im thinking that in the $L^1$ case since i have that the simple functions are going to be in that set and a function in $L^1$ is going to be the limit of these said functions and i can show that its dense.But i still dont see why this wouldnt work in $L^\infty$ need to find a counterexample

Comment: Consider a constant non-zero function and let some sequence in $L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$ converge toward it w.r.t. the $L^{\infty}$ Norm, what happens to the limit of the $L^1$ Norm of that sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any integrable $f$. By Lebesgue's dominated convergence we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f-f\cdot 1_{|f|\leq n}| = 0  $$
but $f\cdot 1_{|f|\leq n}$ belongs to $L^1\cap L^\infty$, so it's dense in $L^1$.

For the second one, take $f\equiv 1$. Then suppose there is $g\in L^1\cap L^\infty$ so that $$||f-g||_\infty<1/2 $$ then $$1/2<g<3/2\ a. e.   $$but this is contradiction with the fact that $g\in L^1$. So $||f-g||_\infty\geq 1/2$ for any such $g$, so $f$ can't be approximated by elements of $L^1\cap L^\infty$, which means it's not dense in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Two things , shouldnt that be a contradiction that $g \in L^1$? And doesnt my argument with the simple functions work? im just curious.

Comment: Yes, of course it should be $L^1$. With simple functions it should work too